# hashicorp vault delete recursively

Tags: bash, hashicorp-vault

What's the cleanest way to delete secrets recursively from Vault? I found a [git issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/885) about this from 2015, with latest answers from 2018, but none of the solutions are native. Is there still no native way to do it?

The path I'm trying to delete is a mix of direct secrets and nested directories, something like so:

```
foo/bar/
    baz/
        secret1
            keypair1
    secret2
        keypair2
        keypair3
    secret3
        keypair4
```

The best solution I can think of now is a bunch of `for x in vault kv list...` nested to catch everything, but that seems so inelegant. Am I missing a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no recursive delete in vault at the moment. You'd be limited in solutions like the ones you mentioned (list stuff and delete manual).

Answer (score 1):

I use python lib https://hvac.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

```py
import hvac
client = hvac.Client(url=server_url)

login_response = client.auth.ldap.login(
    username="xxxx",
    password="xxxx",
)
def list_kv(path: str, mount_point: str) -> List[str]:
    resp = []
    list_secrets_result = client.secrets.kv.v1.list_secrets(path=path, mount_point=mount_point)
    for i in list_secrets_result['data']['keys']:
        resp.append(path+i)
    return resp


def delete_kv(path: str, mount_point: str) -> None:
    ls = list_kv(path, mount_point=mount_point)
    for i in ls:
        if i.endswith("/"):
            delete_kv(i, mount_point=mount_point)
        else:
            print(i)
            response = client.secrets.kv.v1.delete_secret(path=i, mount_point=mount_point)
            print(response)
```

You just need call this function

```py
delete_kv(path='foo/bar/', mount_point='secret')
```